# Anaconda.org uploading errors

Tags: python, anaconda, conda

I'm having 2 errors with uploading ipynb files to anaconda.org.

1.
I downloaded my file from Jupiter notebook as a ipynb file and typed `anaconda upload myfile.ipynb`

But it keeps showing File `"myfile.ipynb" does not exist` even if I clearly see it on my Mac.

2.
When I tried uploading after a hour, I could upload it on anaconda.org (I still don't know what caused the issue)

I wanted to upload a updated version of myfile, so tried `anaconda upload myfile.ipynb` again.

There was no error occurred in terminal, but when I opened anaconda.org, it was still the 1st version, not the updated version.

I kept happening, so I changed the name of the updated version to myfile2 and tried uploading.

And now the first error I mentioned above is happening again.

I simply don't understand why this is happening and how I can fix it.